# sql issue of 'IN' syntax in Avatica calcite

Tags: druid, apache-calcite

I'm using Avatica calcite as a JDBC driver to query  Druid DB. I found the 'IN' syntax CAN NOT followed by more than 19 elements. e.g

```
SELECT * FROM ds1 WHERE city_id IN 
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
```

this works, but this one errors:

```
SELECT * FROM ds1 WHERE city_id IN 
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
```

how can I use the 'IN' syntax with more than 19 elements ?

Comment: `SELECT ... IN (1-19) UNION ALL SELECT ... IN (20-39)`

Comment: I tried this UNION ALL syntax but no luck..., it seems that druid/avatica not support this kind of syntax

Comment: Does `city_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) OR city_id IN (20)` work?

Comment: @melpomene, Both (1-19) and (20) works, but (1-20) not work, it's the number of elements that matters

Comment: @rellocswood The suggestion was to just use an `OR` in your `WHERE` clause to combine multiple `IN` clauses.

Comment: Thanks @Michael ,I've used the <code>OR</code> as workground ,just want to know that will this <code>IN</code> issue be added to the fixing plan of Avatica ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is described in https://github.com/druid-io/druid/issues/4203. It should be fixed in Druid SQL after Calcite 1.14 is released, which will let us customize its behavior a bit more.

Until then, try the workaround suggested by @melpomene, which should work:

```
SELECT * FROM ds1 WHERE
     city_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
  OR city_id IN (20,21,22)
```